# Definite article and dates without ordinal indicators

Tags: grammaticality, definite-articles, dates

Where ordinal indicators are not used, which of the following is correct?

1. We will go ahead *on the 7 January 2013.*
2. We will go ahead *on 7 January 2013.*

Answer (score 4):

[UK answer]

It makes no difference whether ordinal indicators are used or not. When writing, don't use the definite article; when speaking, do use it (whether it's written or not).

Write this:

> We will go ahead on 7 January 2013.
>   We will go ahead on 7th January 2013.

Read both of those as:

> “We will go ahead on the seventh of January 2013.”